# Automatically change subject of sent email

Tags: c#, email, vbscript, outlook

is it possible by code/script/pop server or in the configuration of outlook, to change the subject of a sent email, or whenever the email auto populate from a third party,

let's say each time you find "Blank Invoice" in the subject you replace it by "Invoice",
or to have some kind of macro that will do the find and replace automatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, trap the Aplication.ItemSend event, examine the item passed as the parameter to your event handler, change its subject.

Comment: Is that from the outlook api?

Comment: Yes, Outlook Object Mode. You can do that from a COM addin (preferable since it always runs when Outlook runs), external application, or a VBA project.